# How do I fix my Hotmail background color?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook, hotmail

I want Hotmail (on Chrome) to be dark, but it now this unexpectedly these weird light grayd, and making a new message changes the background as I type.

I believe I changed some color setting in Windows 10 to fix another issue a week ago and this may be the unexpected consequence.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This almost seems (from the look of the image you are sharing) that you turned on 'High Contrast' in Windows.

Click 'Start' > 'Settings' > 'Ease of Access' > 'High Contrast' (Under the Vision menu to the left of the window)

Or you could have selected a 'Theme' from outlook.com. On Outlook.com click the 'gear' icon, under 'Theme' click 'View all' and try out a different theme. Also, try 'Dark mode' on/off.

The last thing could be you are pasting the format from another location with a style on the text. Select all of the text copy (or cut) it and then 'right click' in the text field and select 'paste as plain text'.

That would remove any font style that could be showing up. I know I have to do this with Exchange web access as the font styling is always pasted from the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to [turn on dark mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dark-mode-in-outlook-com-and-outlook-on-the-web-391487d7-c2c0-4256-a5af-b49d0b36a645#:%7E:text=How%20do%20I%20turn%20on%20dark%20mode%3F)?

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.